# Not able to see Tables in SQL Developer after connecting

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to SQL Developer.I am using  4.0.3.16.84-x64 version.After entering the connection details test connection is showing success and I am able to login successfully but when I click on the expand button beside the connection name no tables are appearing. Note with same connection parameters I am able to connect and successfully see the tables in my friend's machine.

[image]

Comment: No idea; but, why wouldn't you upgrade to the most recent SQL Developer version (17.4 at the moment)?

Comment: what @Littlefoot said, for best support, run a more current version. I'm not sure what type of DB you're connected to, you can try 'show jdbc' run with F5, but i'm not sure if that command will work in 4.0 or not

Comment: @Littlefoot I have tried with latest version also but same problem is coming.

Comment: OK, you don't see anything on the left side of the screen. On the right hand side, you selected from dual. Now, try to run `select * from user_objects`. What is the result? Is there anything there? According to what you explained in the question, there should be as your colleague sees objects when connected to the same user.

Comment: @Littlefoot There is no output when I tried to run the query suggested.Similar to that when queried for dual.

Comment: If query I suggested doesn't return anything, then there are no objects in your schema, which means that there's nothing that SQL Developer could display, which means that you - after all - don't connect using the same credentials as your friend. BTW, what do you mean by saying that it is "similar to that when queried for dual"? `select * from dual` **always** returns one row. If it doesn't, your database is screwed up.